# How to use rollback in asp while inserting to linked online server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, rollback, linked-server

In my asp.net application, online syncing option is used. i.e, when syncing data from offline database is transferred to online db using linked server in sql. Syncing is working fine but, features like db.rollback.
Here is my asp code:

```
DB.BeginTrans();

            result = DB.ExecuteScalar_SP("SyncDatabase").ToString(); ;
            if (result == "1")
            {
                DB.CommitTrans();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                DB.RollBack();
                return "0";
            }
```

Here when executing, execute_scalar shows error

> {"The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider \"SQLNCLI11\" for linked server \"194.0.252.134\" was unable to begin a distributed transaction."}

If I remove DB.Begintrans,DB.CommitTrans() and DB.RollBack, Syncing perfoms without any error.

I would like to enable rollback feature, as there is many possible errors to happen when syncing. Is there any other way to perform this syncing securely.
Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to maybe use some other method for syncing, like replication or log shipping - things which are part of SQL Server itself and are designed for keeping two databases synchronised. That's assuming this is a one-way sync. If it's bi-directional you might have to do a bit more research. But a simple stored procedure is unlikely to be a good solution, as you've realised.

Comment: I think only possible syncing for my purpose is this. because, offline and online database will not exact replicatoin. Only particular data is synced. Though, I will check this out. Everything is working fine, but only this rollback feature is missing, which is a must @ADyson

Comment: Replication can be programmed to only sync certain data and also to transform it if needed.

Comment: Can you suggest any good tutorials to implement replicatoin through asp.net and sql. I am a beginner in these. Does replication help in rollback feature. @ADyson

Comment: It's not implemented through .net, it's a feature in SQL Server itself. You can manage it through SQL Management Studio. Simply google for SQL Server Replication and you'll find lots of documentation and other guides

Comment: I want the syncing to performed from inside my web application, not through management studio. And also it will performed when user click sync button @ADyson

Comment: But why make it like that? It can sync in the background automatically without user intervention. Surely that's much better? Or you can make a button in .NET which will trigger the replication client to run, perhaps (by running the right SQL command), I don't know, you can google it. But either way you have to use Management studio (or raw SQL) to set up the replication, after that you might be able to use your application to control it, but I don't see much advantage in that compared to the default, which is automation.

Comment: Ok.. let me check into it. If you have any further information, kindly let me know.. Thank you @ADyson